# What hook for WooCommerce plain email notifications after customer details?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

Is there a hook just below the shipping address displayed in Woocommerce plain emails?

I need to insert some text below the shipping field but I can only find hooks that will display the text either in the order sum or product name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following hook with a priority above **`20`**, targeting plain emails, that will display anything desired after customer details (after billing and shipping address section):

```
add_action ('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'action_email_customer_details_callback', 21, 4);
function action_email_customer_details_callback( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    // Only for "Plain text" email notifications
    if ( ! $plain_text ) return;

    // Your code goes here below
    echo '<p>'.__("Test").'</p>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.